# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, reporting-services

I'm a newbie to .NET, and kind of don't know what I'm doing.

I have a project that I have updated from .NET 3.5 to 4.5 in Visual Studio 2019. I am running into the error described in the title. Acting on various other answers from this site, I have tried re-installing the NuGet package for 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms' and installing the NuGet package for 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.Common'. The `.dll` files all seem to be in the `bin` folder of the project. I also think all the references in my `web.config` page are updated and match in my code. What could I be missing?

For reference, here is the code that shows the error:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="rsweb" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.40219.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[something]" %>
```

Please let me know if I should any other code/details in.

Comment: The version you have is different.

Comment: The version I have specified in the web.config file is the same as the one I gave above (10.0.40219.1). Is this not enough? Is there another place I have to change the version?

Comment: If the code recompiled from older version.  It may be that the old code did not compile.  You can check the date of all executables (dlls) and see if they have changed.

Comment: Out of curiosity do you also have the microsoft.reportviewer.common dll? I believe that you need both of these referenced.

Comment: Yes. Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll is also in my bin folder

Comment: Does the <%@ Register assembly property actually have `[something]`? If so, that's likely the issue... If not, you can use the [Fusion Log Viewer](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) to view details w/ assembly binding errors which would give more info